# Undermount Bathroom Sink mounting

Tags: bathroom, sink

I am mounting this undermount sink I bought in Home Depot. It is a bathroom sink. I am planning to mount these with the overflow holes towards the front i.e. where user will be standing and not where the faucets will be.

Is there anything I should be aware of or paying attention to?

The drain hole is not in the center but instead it is closer to the face that doesn't have the overflow hole. In fact, the face that does not have the overflow hole is straight vertically where as the face that has the overflow hole is kind of sloping gradually to the bottom.

I believe it can be mounted either way but am I wrong? Am I missing something? Is there anything crucial I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Arya

Update: The brand is MR Direct. Also, called them directly but the support person was of not much help. He said he doesn't have any more information beyond whatever is posted on their website. I had already looked into all that documentation before asking the question. TIA

[image]

Comment: Looking at several of these on the HD site, Most show your design with the overflow on the face with the vertical surface in the back.  What makes you think that you are installing it backward?

Answer (score 1):

Why you did not provide the specific brand you are installing, looking at several of these sinks similar to your design on the HD site.  Most show your design with the overflow on the face with the vertical surface in the back. What makes you think that you are installing it backward?

There should be no issue installing it with the overflow hole in the front.

Comment: The brand is MR Direct. Sorry left out the information inadvertently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The overflow almost always gets installed on the front.   But really you need to RTFM.   There is nothing we can answer that the sink's guide wouldn't answer in 10 seconds.

Also drain holes can be where ever.   They could be on the left side of the sink.   As long as water flows that way, it works.   There is no requirement or need for a drain hole to be anywhere.   It may require you to have a certain cabinet (for instance a cabinet with 1/3 drawers may have an issue with an offset drain) or it may require you to redo your plumbing but the sink manufacturer does not care.

Comment: Read everything I could for the sink and also called the manufacturer. Unfortunately not much help - the support person said they don't have any more information than the one on their website (which I had already read).

Comment: @arya If the manufacturer can not provide simple info like this, then time to get a new manufacturer! There's plenty of good ones such as Toto, Kohler, Kallista, Villeroy & Boch, etc.

Comment: @GlenYates - it also probably doesn't matter in what direction an undermount sink is installed.   For instance when we do kitchens and someone gets an undermount that is a perfect rectangle with two bays... we ask them do you want the big or the little bay on the left.   The plumbing will be different that is all.   Here... the overflow being right by the faucet might look odd but everything will functionally work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there existing plumbing, or are you installing new?

If you're trying to match the new sink to the old plumbing, check to see which orientation works better. There might not be enough horizontal adjustability to the drain line to accommodate one orientation, and your decision is made for you!

That said, most modern sinks I've seen are installed with drain holes closer to the user (so you don't look directly at them while you're standing at the sink).

A sink in the house I grew up in was installed the other way, and when I stepped up to that sink I always stared at the mysterious, slightly rusty drain hole and wondered what was down there, and whether it could see me. Happy Halloween :)